# single dice roll simulation with C++

Tags: c++, random

I am writing a program to simulate a dice roll with random function. 
This is my code, but I am having infinite loop.
The program is supposed to ask the user how many times they would like to roll the dice.
Then I used a for loop to roll the dice from 1 to 6
and I put all that in a do-while in order to only allow the user to select between 1 and 6 , if the selection is outside of 1 to 6 it is supposed to say it is an invalid selection. 
I am not allowed to use functions or arrays on this

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //i is the counter for the loop
    int i = 0; 
    //store total count for landing number
    int num1 =0;
    int num2 =0;
    int num3 =0;
    int num4 =0;
    int num5 =0;
    int num6 =0;

    int Num1 =0;
    int Num2 =0;
    int Num3 =0;
    int Num4 =0;
    int Num5 =0;
    int Num6 =0;
    int randNum;
    int times;


    //User selection
    int selection;


    /* initialize random seed: */
   srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));

   /* generate random number: */
   randNum = rand() % 6 + 1;

    cout<<"How many times would you like to roll the dice? " << endl;
    cin >> selection;

   do{
        for(i = 1; i <= selection; i++)
        {

            if(randNum==1)
            {
                num1++;
            }
            else if(randNum==2)
            {
                num2++;
            }
            else if(randNum==3)
            {
                num3++;
            }
            else if(randNum==4)
            {
                num4++;
            }
            else if(randNum==5)
            {
                num5++;
            }
            else if(randNum==6)
            {
                num6++;
            }
        }
    Num1 = num1/times *100;
    Num2 = num2/times *100;
    Num3 = num3/times *100;
    Num4 = num4/times *100;
    Num5 = num5/times *100;
    Num6 = num6/times *100;


    cout <<"# Rolled \t # Times \t % Times" << endl;
    cout <<"----- \t ------- \t -------" << endl;
    cout <<" 1 \t " << num1 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num1 << "%\n";
    cout <<" 2 \t " << num2 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num2 << "%\n";
    cout <<" 3 \t " << num3 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num3 << "%\n";
    cout <<" 4 \t " << num4 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num4 << "%\n";
    cout <<" 5 \t " << num5 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num5 << "%\n";
    cout <<" 6 \t " << num6 << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Num6 << "%\n";
    }

   while(i >= 1 || i <= 6);
   {
       cout << "This is an invalid number. \n"
        << "The number of rolls should be equal to or greater than 1.\n"
        << "Please enter again.\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems you want to check for valid input before you do all the other work and output.  You might consider an array for the counts, it would be much simpler code. `times` is uninitialized when you use it, and integer math is going to give you incorrect values. You might also put the dice rolling inside the for loop.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your code, one line at a time, what was the reason why the code execute your "infinite loop"?

Comment: Hi, I am not allowed to use array or function to this code

Comment: You probably want to generate the random number in the loop.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use array or function" - then learn programming from some other source.

Comment: Develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible, If you're learning how to roll a die, write a program that rolls a die-- and don't mate it to other code until it works perfectly. Most of the code above is unrelated to this task.

Comment: Avoid `rand()` at all costs, it is extremely problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional statement: `i = 1; i <= selection; i++` should go in the final while you have.

Try:

```
do {
    if (randNum==1) {
        num1++;
    } else if(randNum==2) {
        num2++;
    } else if(randNum==3) {
        num3++;
    } else if(randNum==4) {
        num4++;
    } else if(randNum==5) {
        num5++;
    } else if(randNum==6) {
       num6++;
    }
    i += 1;
} while (i <= selection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is the `do` - `while`...

I'm not sure what you were trying to do there, but you will always get a number greater than 1 or smaller than 6 in your test - you can't fail both...